# Is there something wrong with this javascript?

Tags: javascript

So this is externally linked, that works fine. But when I run it in the browser, it does not show anything. Is there anything wrong with this code?

```js
var myheading = "This is my webpage!";
var text = "This JavaScript file makes use of Variables";
var linktag = "http://www.google.com/";
var begineffect = "<strong>";
var endeffect = "</strong>";
var linebreak = "<br />";
function numberone(myheading) {
  document.write("<h2>" +myheading+ "</h2>");
}
numberone(myheading)
function numbertwo(text) {
  document.write("<strong>" +text+ "</strong>");
}
numbertwo(text)
function numberthree(linktag) {
  document.write( +linktag+ );
}
numberthree(linktag)
```

Comment: `document.write( +linktag+ );` Plus on both sides?

Comment: Consider looking at the browser console. You’d see the error

Answer (score 0):

There are two extra `+` to remove in the `document.write` of the 'numberthree' function, *i.e.*:

```js
var myheading = "This is my webpage!";
var text = "This JavaScript file makes use of Variables";
var linktag = "http://www.google.com/";
var begineffect = "<strong>";
var endeffect = "</strong>";
var linebreak = "<br />";
function numberone(myheading) {
  document.write("<h2>" +myheading+ "</h2>");
}
numberone(myheading)
function numbertwo(text) {
  document.write("<strong>" +text+ "</strong>");
}
numbertwo(text)
function numberthree(linktag) {
  document.write(linktag);
}
numberthree(linktag)
```